# Comparision of two fields in progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have buffer bufCustomer for table Customer global buffer gbufOrder  for table Order.
But this code is not working I wrote the code like
find bufCustomer where bufCustomer.CustomerID = gbufOrder.CustomerID no-lock no-error.
but if i check the table data,data is there but if i wrote a code like above its not working.
Is there any other way to get the values?

Comment: You need to show your actual code.  The description is far too vague to reach any conclusions from.

Comment: define buffer bufCustomer for Customer.                                                             find bufCustomer where bufCustomer.CustomerID = gbufOrder.CustomerID no-lock no-error

Comment: I want to get Customer Name so I wrote this which is working partially i.e getting customer Name for some of the records but i want to get the customer name for all records.Please help.

Comment: try run your script without the NO-ERROR option in the FIND statement. you should then receive an error, which explain you, what is wrong...

Comment: Its showing like "bufCustomer record not found".HOw to get the values?

Answer (score 1):

w/BUFFER:

```
DEFINE BUFFER gbufOrder FOR Order.
DEFINE BUFFER bufCustomer FOR Customer.

FIND FIRST gbufOrder NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE(gbufOrder) THEN
   DO:
      FIND bufCustomer where bufCustomer.CustNum = gbufOrder.CustNum NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

      IF AVAILABLE(bufCustomer) THEN
         DO:
            DISP bufCustomer.name.
         END.
      ELSE
         DO:
            MESSAGE "Customer is not available!"
               VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
         END.
   END.
ELSE
   DO:
      MESSAGE "Order is not available!"
          VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
   END.
```

w/o BUFFER

```
FIND FIRST Order NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE(Order) THEN
   DO:
      FIND Customer where Customer.CustNum = Order.CustNum NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

      IF AVAILABLE(Customer) THEN
         DO:
            DISP Customer.name.
         END.
      ELSE
         DO:
            MESSAGE "Customer is not available!"
               VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
         END.
   END.
ELSE
   DO:
      MESSAGE "Order is not available!"
          VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
   END.
```

This program works with `sports200` sample database (it is located in PROGRESS / OpenEdge install directory)

UPDATE:

- checking availbility of Customer
- add sample code without BUFFER

Comment: that is not yet 100% correct. you should testing the availablity of bufcustomer after the FIND bufCustomer - like after first FIND of Order. else get you some error like customer not available..